# AWS Cognito - pass details from client to custom message trigger

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

According to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html#CognitoUserPools-InitiateAuth-request-ClientMetadata)

**ClientMetadata** will not be provided inside **custom message trigger**.
Are there alternatives/workarounds, to pass **ClientMetadata** to **custom message trigger** using purely cognito hooks/triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this, by using a cognito hook(**pre-authentication**) that is triggered before **custom message** hook.

My use case, is to send a custom message to a user, depending on the content of **ClientMetadata** provided by user.

I was able to achieve this, because **pre-authentication** hook executes before **custom message** hook.

I was able to save the **ClientMetadata** somewhere in server on **pre-auth hook**, then fetch it when the next hook(**custom message**) triggers. Not very fancy, but was done w/ pure cognito hooks :))